# Specifying a non-linear relation between random effects in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, multi-level, nlme, r2jags

I'm working with multilevel models to try and describe different patterns in longitudinal change. [Dingemanse et al (2010)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169534709002432) describe a 'fanning out' pattern when the random effects are perfectly correlated. However I found that a similar pattern occurs when the relationship between random effects is non-linear but monotonically increasing over the observed interval. In this case random effects are not perfectly correlated but described by a function.
See example below for an illustration of this. The example still has a high intercept-slope correlation (>.9) but it is possible to get correlations lower than .7 while still maintaining a perfect intercept-slope relation.

My question: Is there a way to include a perfect (non-linear) relationship between random effects in a multilevel model using `nlme` or some other R package? MLwiN has a way to constrain the slope-intercept covariance, that would be a start but is not sufficient to include non-linear relations. I've been unable to find solutions for `nlme` so far, but maybe you know of some other package that can include this in the model.

Apologies for the sloppy coding. I hope that my question is sufficiently clear but let me know if anything needs to be clarified. Any help or alternative solution is greatly appreciated.

```
set.seed(123456)

# Change function, quadratic
# Yit = B0ij + B1ij*time + B2ij*time^2
chn <- function(int, slp, slp2, time){
  score<-int + slp * time+ slp2 * time^2 
  return(score)
}


# Set N, random intercept, time and ID
N<-100
start<-rnorm(N,100,15) # Random intercept
time<- matrix(1:15,ncol = 15, nrow = 100,byrow = T) # Time, balanced panel data
ID<-1:N # ID variable

# Random intercept, linear slope: exp(intercept/25)/75, quadratic slope: exp(intercept/25)/250 
score3<-matrix(NA,ncol = ncol(time), nrow = N)
for(x in ID){
  score3[x,]<-chn(start[x],exp(start[x]/25)/75,exp(start[x]/25)/250,time[x,])
}

#Create dataframe
df<- data.frame(ID,score3)
df2<- melt(df,id = 'ID')
df2$variable<-as.vector(time)


# plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x= variable, y= value)) + geom_line(aes(group = ID)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), se =F, size = 2, col ="red" )


# Add noise and estimate model
df2$value2<-df2$value + rnorm(N*ncol(time),0,2)

# Random intercept
mod1<-lme(value2 ~ variable + I(variable^2),
          random= list(ID = ~1),
          data=df2,method="ML",na.action=na.exclude)
summary(mod1)

# Random slopes
mod2<-update(mod1,.~.,random= list(ID = ~variable + I(variable^2)))
summary(mod2)


pairs(ranef(mod2))
```

Comment: Could always go Bayesian...

Comment: I was thinking about going Bayesian but only have limited experience with R2WinBUGS and R2jags. If you could show me an example it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MattTyers It took some time, but I made an attempt with the rjags package. Any feedback is welcome though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by @MattTyers I had a go with a Bayesian approach using `rjags`. It's a first attempt on simulated data with a known relation between the random effects but seems to yield accurate estimates (better then the `nlme` model). I am still a bit worried about the Gelman convergence diagnostic and how to apply this solution to actual data. However, I figured I'd post my answer in case someone is working on the same problem.

```
# BAYESIAN ESTIMATE
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
# Set new dataset
set.seed(12345)

# New dataset to separate random and fixed
N<-100              # Number of respondents
int<-100            # Fixed effect intercept
U0<-rnorm(N,0,15)   # Random effect intercept
slp_lin<-1          # Fixed effect linear slope
slp_qua<-.25        # Fixed effect quadratic slope
ID<- 1:100          # ID numbers
U1<-exp(U0/25)/7.5  # Random effect linear slope
U2<-exp(U0/25)/25   # Random effect quadratic slope
times<-15           # Max age
err <- matrix(rnorm(N*times,0,2),ncol = times, nrow = N) # Residual term
age <- 1:15         # Ages

# Create matrix of 'math' scores using model
math<-matrix(NA,ncol = times, nrow = N)

for(i in ID){

  for(j in age){

math[i,j] <- (int + U0[i]) + 
  (slp_lin + U1[i])*age[j] + 
  (slp_qua + U2[i])*(age[j]^2) + 
  err[i,j] 

}}

# Melt dataframe and plot scores
e.long<-melt(math)
names(e.long) <- c("ID","age","math")
ggplot(e.long,aes(x= age, y= math)) + geom_line(aes(group = ID))

# Create dataframe for rjags
dat<-list(math=as.numeric(e.long$math),
          age=as.numeric(e.long$age), 
          childnum=e.long$ID,
          n=length(e.long$math), 
          nkids=length(unique(e.long$ID)))
lapply(dat , summary)


library(rjags)

# Model with uninformative priors
model_rnk<-"
model{

#Model, fixed effect age and random intercept-slope connected
for( i in 1:n)
{
  math[i]~dnorm(mu[i], sigm.inv)
  mu[i]<-(b[1] + u[childnum[i],1]) + (b[2]+ u[childnum[i],2]) * age[i] + 
  (b[3]+ u[childnum[i],3]) * (age[i]^2) 
}

#Random slopes
for (j in 1:nkids)
{
  u[j, 1] ~ dnorm(0, tau.a)
  u[j, 2] <- exp(u[j,1]/25)/7.5
  u[j, 3] <- exp(u[j,1]/25)/25
}

#Priors on fixed intercept and slope priors
b[1] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-5)
b[2] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-5)
b[3] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-5)

# Residual variance priors
sigm.inv ~ dgamma(1.5, 0.001)# precision of math[i]
sigm<- pow(sigm.inv, -1/2)   # standard deviation


# Varying intercepts, varying slopes priors
tau.a ~ dgamma(1.5, 0.001)
sigma.a<-pow(tau.a, -1/2)
}"

#Initialize the model
mod_rnk<-jags.model(file=textConnection(model_rnk), data=dat, n.chains=2 )

#burn in 
update(mod_rnk, 5000)

#collect samples of the parameters
samps_rnk<-coda.samples(mod_rnk, variable.names=c( "b","sigma.a", "sigm"), n.iter=5000, n.thin=1)

#Numerical summary of each parameter:
summary(samps_rnk)

gelman.diag(samps_rnk,  multivariate = F)

# nlme model
library(nlme)
Stab_rnk2<-lme(math ~ age + I(age^2),
               random= list(ID = ~age + I(age^2)),
               data=e.long,method="ML",na.action=na.exclude)
summary(Stab_rnk2)
```

The outcome looks very close to the population values

```
1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

                Mean       SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
    b[1]    100.7409 0.575414 5.754e-03      0.1065523
    b[2]      0.9843 0.052248 5.225e-04      0.0064052
    b[3]      0.2512 0.003144 3.144e-05      0.0003500
    sigm      1.9963 0.037548 3.755e-04      0.0004056
    sigma.a  16.9322 1.183173 1.183e-02      0.0121340
```

And the nlme estimates are far worse (with the exception of the random intercept)

```
Random effects:
 Formula: ~age + I(age^2) | ID
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev      Corr        
(Intercept) 16.73626521 (Intr) age  
age          0.13152688 0.890       
I(age^2)     0.03752701 0.924  0.918
Residual     1.99346015             

Fixed effects: math ~ age + I(age^2) 
                Value Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 103.85896 1.6847051 1398 61.64816       0
age           1.15741 0.0527874 1398 21.92586       0
I(age^2)      0.30809 0.0048747 1398 63.20204       0
```